# Need to wrap a string at n length, and only keep the bottom 12 lines

Tags: python-3.x, curses

I've been at it for a bit, and the best I can think of is using textwrap, but I can't figure out how to keep it to the last 12 lines using textwrap. Link to the textwrap functions are here https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html

(I'm doing this with curses, so curses functions are open too I guess)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`textwrap.wrap` returns a list of output lines. You can select the last 12  elements in the list with slicing:

```
textwrap.wrap(s, width=20)[-12:]
```

Example:

```
import textwrap

s = "abcdefgh"

# Keep only the last 2 lines
a = textwrap.wrap(s, width=2)[-2:]

print(a)
```

This will output:

```
['ef', 'gh']
```

Comment: thank you! I tried something similar, but was too tired to put it fully together. Thank you!

Comment: If it worked, can you please set it as accepted answer? Thank you!